# Docker compose to AWS ECS fails at the end

Tags: docker-compose, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

Im publishing a project via docker compose to AWS ECR but it fails on the last couple of steps. Its based on the new "docker compose" integration with an AWS context

The error i receive is:

```
MicroservicedocumentGeneratorService TaskFailedToStart: ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve ecr registry auth: service call has been retried 3 time(s): RequestError: send request failed caused by: Post https://api.ecr....
```

The image is in an ECR private repository along with the others from the compose file.

I have authenticated with:

```
aws ecr get-login-password
```

The docker compose is:

```
  microservice_documentGenerator:
    image: xxx.dkr.ecr.xxx.amazonaws.com/microservice_documentgenerator:latest
    networks:
      - publicnet
```

The original dockerfile is

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim
COPY /Microservice.DocumentGenerator/Microservice.DocumentGenerator.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

The output for before the error was:

```
[+] Running 54/54
 - projext                                                 DeleteComplete                                     355.3s
 - PublicnetNetwork                                        DeleteComplete                                     310.5s
 - LogGroup                                                DeleteComplete                                     306.1s
 - MicroservicedocumentGeneratorTaskExecutionRole          DeleteComplete                                     272.2s
 - MicroservicedocumentGeneratorTaskDefinition             Del...                                             251.2s    
 - MicroservicedocumentGeneratorServiceDiscoveryEntry      DeleteComplete                                     220.1s     
 - MicroservicedocumentGeneratorService                    DeleteComp...                                      211.9s
```

Comment: What was the issue? did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Ive marked the below as the correct as it defiantly helped, however there was also some healthch fails. Check your cloudwatch logs before it rolls back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try authentication with:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
```

Plus can you mention from where you are making the call and if the server has the permission to make the call to ECR?

Comment: Thanks but this isnt it. Ive got another 10 images that are all being pulled from the ECR without an issue as ive already come cross the auth problem. This error occurs as the container deploys to the cluster

Comment: You are using AWS Fargate or EC2 launch type with ECS? If Fargate what platform version are you using and if EC2 check the taskRole permission - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html